# Attribute error in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Tried executing `plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))`
where result has the job result and circuit is the Quantum circuit

But an attribute error hits every time.

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_counts'
```

I tried going through the qiskit tutorial documentation, but couldn't help myself with it.

Can somebody point out what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like maybe one of the calls is missed. To get results you need to run

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
job = execute(circ, backend)
result = job.result()
plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))
```

Comment: Hey thanks fella. got it sorted out